# Which is more correct, "Which one do you want?" or "What one do you want?"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, questions

Which of the following is correct?

> 1. Which one do you want?
> 2. What one do you want?

Comment: Please support our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> If you're offering a limited choice, then use *which*: "*Which of these 25 models do you want (to buy/try/look at)?*"

-

> But if there are endless possibilities, use *what*: "*Now that you've won the lottery, what do you want to buy, a Rolls, a Benz, a Ferrari, a Lamborghini?*"

"*What one do you want?*" isn't idiomatic English, but "*Which one do you want?*" is.

Answer (score 1):

In American English, *which one* is a common phrase.  *What one* is not, and it sound very stilted.

Answer (score 0):

*Which* is used to refer to a specific object, while *what* is referring to a more general selection.

In your case, "which *one*" do you want is correct. You can also change it to be "what do you want".